# RuntimeError: Expected 3D (unbatched) or 4D (batched) input to conv2d

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, torchvision, unet-neural-network

**Hey together,
i wrote a code with pytorch to segment satellite-images with a unet.
If I test every block seperatly (unet, dataloader, train()), it works perfectly and it gives me the correct sizes back.
But if I combine them, I get the error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                     
  File "/Users/.../gesamt.py", line 300, in <module>
    train_loss, train_dice = train(model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, device)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/.../gesamt.py", line 251, in train
    outputs = model(inputs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/.../gesamt.py", line 193, in forward
    x1 = self.down_conv_1(image) #
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 217, in forward
    input = module(input)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 463, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 459, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Expected 3D (unbatched) or 4D (batched) input to conv2d, but got input of size: [1, 16, 3, 572, 572]
```

**I know what the problem is, but I cant find the reason the code will not continue using [16, 3, 572, 572] and instead adds the batch_size so that ist runs into an error with [16, 3, 572, 572].**
This is my code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision.transforms import Compose, ToTensor, Normalize
from tqdm import tqdm

class SatelliteDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_dir, mask_dir, transform=None, patch_size=572):
        self.image_dir = image_dir
        self.mask_dir = mask_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.patch_size = patch_size

        # creating a Dictionary, to group masks and images with the same index
        self.image_mask_pairs = self._group_image_mask_pairs()

    def _group_image_mask_pairs(self):
        image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(self.image_dir) if f.endswith(".png")]
        mask_files = [f for f in os.listdir(self.mask_dir) if f.endswith(".png")]
        image_mask_pairs = {}

        for image_file in image_files:
            image_number = self._extract_number_from_filename(image_file)
            for mask_file in mask_files:
                mask_number = self._extract_number_from_filename(mask_file)
                if image_number == mask_number:
                    image_path = os.path.join(self.image_dir, image_file)
                    mask_path = os.path.join(self.mask_dir, mask_file)
                    image_mask_pairs[image_number] = (image_path, mask_path)
                    break

        return image_mask_pairs

    def _extract_number_from_filename(self, filename):
        return int(filename.split('_')[0])

    def _split_image_into_patches(self, image):
        patches = []
        height, width, _ = image.shape
        for y in range(0, height - self.patch_size + 1, self.patch_size):
            for x in range(0, width - self.patch_size + 1, self.patch_size):
                patch = image[y:y + self.patch_size, x:x + self.patch_size]
                patches.append(patch)
        return patches

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_mask_pairs)


    def _apply_transform(self, image, mask):
        if self.transform is not None:
            if self.transform.transforms is not None:
                for t in self.transform.transforms:
                    image = t(image)
                    mask = t(mask)
        return image, mask



    def __getitem__(self, index):
        image_path, mask_path = self.image_mask_pairs[index]

        image = np.array(Image.open(image_path))
        mask = np.array(Image.open(mask_path))

        image_patches = self._split_image_into_patches(image)
        mask_patches = self._split_image_into_patches(mask)

        #Apply transformations to each patch individually
        augmented_image_patches = []
        augmented_mask_patches = []
        for i in range(len(image_patches)):
            augmented_image, augmented_mask = self._apply_transform(image_patches[i], mask_patches[i])
            augmented_image_patches.append(augmented_image)
            augmented_mask_patches.append(augmented_mask)

        #Combine the patches (as Tensors) without transposing channels
        augmented_image = torch.stack(augmented_image_patches)
        augmented_mask = torch.stack(augmented_mask_patches)

        return augmented_image, augmented_mask


def double_conv(in_c, out_c):
    conv = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_c, out_c, kernel_size=3),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(out_c, out_c, kernel_size=3),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
    )
    return conv

def crop_img(tensor, target_tensor):
    target_size = target_tensor.size()[2]
    tensor_size = tensor.size()[2]
    delta = tensor_size - target_size
    delta = delta // 2
    return tensor[:, :, delta:tensor_size-delta, delta:tensor_size-delta]


class UNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels=3, out_channels=7):

        super(UNet, self).__init__()
        self.max_pool_2x2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)


        self.max_pool_2x2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.down_conv_1 = double_conv(3, 64)
        self.down_conv_2 = double_conv(64, 128)
        self.down_conv_3 = double_conv(128, 256)
        self.down_conv_4 = double_conv(256, 512)
        self.down_conv_5 = double_conv(512, 1024)

        self.up_trans_1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(
            in_channels=1024,
            out_channels=512,
            kernel_size=2,
            stride=2)
        
        self.up_conv_1 = double_conv(1024, 512)

        self.up_trans_2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(
            in_channels=512,
            out_channels=256,
            kernel_size=2,
            stride=2)
        
        self.up_conv_2 = double_conv(512, 256)

        self.up_trans_3 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(
            in_channels=256,
            out_channels=128,
            kernel_size=2,
            stride=2)
        
        self.up_conv_3 = double_conv(256, 128)

        self.up_trans_4 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(
            in_channels=128,
            out_channels=64,
            kernel_size=2,
            stride=2)
        
        self.up_conv_4 = double_conv(128, 64)

        self.out = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=64,
            out_channels=7, #Objects to segments
            kernel_size=1
        )



    def forward(self, image):
        #encoder
        x1 = self.down_conv_1(image) #
        x2 = self.max_pool_2x2(x1)
        x3 = self.down_conv_2(x2) #
        x4 = self.max_pool_2x2(x3)
        x5 = self.down_conv_3(x4) #
        x6 = self.max_pool_2x2(x5)
        x7 = self.down_conv_4(x6)
        x8 = self.max_pool_2x2(x7)
        x9 = self.down_conv_5(x8)

        #decoder
        x = self.up_trans_1(x9)
        y = crop_img(x7, x)
        x = self.up_conv_1(torch.cat([x, y], 1))

        x = self.up_trans_2(x)
        y = crop_img(x5, x)
        x = self.up_conv_2(torch.cat([x, y], 1))

        x = self.up_trans_3(x)
        y = crop_img(x3, x)
        x = self.up_conv_3(torch.cat([x, y], 1))

        x = self.up_trans_4(x)
        y = crop_img(x1, x)
        x = self.up_conv_4(torch.cat([x, y], 1))

        x = self.out(x)
        print(x.size())
        return x

# calculates the Dice-Koeffizient
def dice_coefficient(pred, target):
    smooth = 1.0
    intersection = (pred * target).sum()
    dice = (2.0 * intersection + smooth) / (pred.sum() + target.sum() + smooth)
    return dice

# train-function
def train(model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, device):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    running_dice = 0.0

    for inputs, masks in tqdm(train_loader, desc="Training", leave=False):
        inputs, masks = inputs.to(device), masks.to(device)

        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        outputs = model(inputs)
        print(f"outputs size: {outputs.size()}")
        loss = criterion(outputs, masks)
        dice = dice_coefficient(outputs.argmax(dim=1), masks.argmax(dim=1))
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        running_loss += loss.item()
        running_dice += dice.item()
        
    epoch_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader)
    epoch_dice = running_dice / len(train_loader)
    return epoch_loss, epoch_dice



# Configuration for the training
image_dir = "/Users/.../img_path/"
mask_dir = "/Users/.../mask_path/"
patch_size = 572
batch_size = 16
learning_rate = 0.001
num_epochs = 1
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Instanz for Datasets and DataLoader
transform = Compose([
    ToTensor(),
    Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])
dataset = SatelliteDataset(image_dir, mask_dir, transform=transform, patch_size=patch_size)
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# Instanz of the modell and the optimizer
model = UNet(in_channels=3, out_channels=7)  # Passe out_channels an die Anzahl der Objekte an, die segmentiert werden sollen
model.to(device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)


# start the training
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    print("hi")
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}")
    train_loss, train_dice = train(model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, device)
    print(f"Train Loss: {train_loss:.4f} | Train Dice: {train_dice:.4f}")
    print("hallo")

# save the model
torch.save(model.state_dict(), "trainiertes_modell.pth")
```

I searched the internet and stackoverflow to find solutions for zhis problem. I found some with similiar error messages but the solutions for that didnt help because i cant find why my code is adding the 16 to the size.
I also ask ChatGPT, but it also didnt find a working solution.

I hope some of you can help me what is going on.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are producing a series of images in your dataset `__get_item__` and use typical train loop which is designed for one image

I guess the size of output in this method is (16, 3, 572, 572) (check it in debug) , then you run Dataloader with batch size 1 , and you have a five dimension tensor of size: [1, 16, 3, 572, 572] which is not fit to Conv2d.

You can either:

1. Correct `get_item` to produce a tensor in form of (C,H,W) **or**
2. Squeeze `inputs, masks` from (B,16,C,H,W) to (B*16, C, H, W)